# Make keyboard disappear when clicking outside of Search Bar - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

I have a UIViewController and I have embedded a Search Bar and a Collection View.  When I press on the searchbar, the keyboard appears.  I would like to hide this keyboard if the user decides to change his mind by tapping any where on the screen but the search bar.  I have tried the following without success:

1. Adding a Tap Gesture Recognizer
2. using 'self.mySearchBar.endEditing(true)'

   ```
   class CollectionViewFolder: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate{

   /*** OUTLETS ***/
   @IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!


   // 1. I have tried adding a Tap Gesture Recognizer
   // TAP ON SCREEN LISTENER
   @IBAction func tapOnScreen(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      print("tap tap ...")
      self.mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
   }



   // 2.  Added the following to the viewDidLoad:
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      self.mySearchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

   }
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this extension.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Usage. In your viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}
```

Comment: my class is already  subclass of UIViewController - i don't understand the extension bit...

Comment: This extension approaches to any controller. You should just copy extension to your project anywhere you want, than you can call hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() method in any viewController.