# iOS - How to dismiss keyboard from the navigationItem.searchController when tap anywhere on the UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented the new `SearchController` with its `searchBar` and the `searchResultsController`.

Here is how I implemented it :

The resultViewController:

```
lazy var resultViewController: SearchResultViewController = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let searchResultViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultViewController") as! SearchResultViewController
    searchResultViewController.delegate = self
    return searchResultViewController
}()
```

And this is the SearchController:

```
lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultViewController)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search.city.label".localizable()
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: searchController.searchBar)]).tintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.47, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)

    if let textfield = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            // Rounded corner
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }

    definesPresentationContext = true
    return searchController
}()
```

In my `viewWillAppear` I set the navigationItem.searchController :

```
self.searchController.isActive = true

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

I have been able to handle the cancelButtonClicked :

```
extension HomeViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.searchController.isActive = false
    }
}
```

This is doing the "cancel" animation, hiding keyboard + inactive state on searchBar/searchController. Both at the same time, with 1 tap on cancel Button.

But I am unable to achieve this when the user tap anywhere on the view.

I tried with tap gesture but it requires me 2 tap to achieve the same behavior.

**NB:**

I got an UICollectionView in my UIViewController, which takes all the place in the UIView.

Here is what I have tried :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    handleTapAnywhereToRemoveKeyboard()
}


func handleTapAnywhereToRemoveKeyboard() {
    let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.singleTap(sender:)))
    //singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func singleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.searchController.isActive = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}
```

**EDIT:**

I was thinking, maybe it's because my searchBar and searchController aren't in the UIViewController's view hierarchy, but more in the NavigationController one.

So I also tried with :

```
navigationController?.view.endEditing(true)
```

I then was thinking, maybe it's because the UIScrollView within my UICollectionView is catching the tap.
So I tried to link the tap gesture on the UICollectionView instead of the UIView, but without success.

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019084/8417137

Comment: OP has said that, with that solution, two taps are necessary. So not the answer.

Comment: I have edited my post. @AlexKolovatov your solution is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` as proposed above. `UIViewContoller` already conforms to `UIResponder` interface (legacy from Objective C), so you can override this method like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            self.view.window?.endEditing(true)
            super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please create `UIViewController` for dismiss keyboard througout application.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Use above code in your `UIViewController` file as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() 
}
```

**Update:**

You can also use below code to dismiss keyboard from any class.

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resign‌​FirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

Comment: Isn't it the same answer than @Alex Kolovatov ?

Comment: The solution in the update was perfect for me. Easy to use oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution from Dimple Desai but add the gesture recognizer to the TableView or CollectionView or whatever is laying on top of your UIView. Then it should work.

Comment: It has the same behaviour with the tap gesture added on the collectionView : it requires 2 taps to close the keyboard, first one put the search bar in its normal state, second tap close the keyboard. With a side effect: I cannot tap on my cells anymore.. Too bad I thought you had the solution..

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

   let tapView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideKeyboard))
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapView)
}

@objc func hideKeyboard(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){

   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: please explain the problem at-least!

Comment: when we tap anywhere in the screen,keyboard is hidden.Using the gesture we hide the keyboard